# how do I use pcov in python to get errors for each parameter?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a code and used curve_fit to fir both Lorentz and gaussin curves to the data.
I need to get error estimates for each parameter outputted, so have printed both the popt and pcov
I know the scipy reference guide states how to use pcov matrix to find the errors however this is unclear to me as I am a novice at programming.
thanks

Answer (score 5):

Reading the docs can often provide answers to such questions. For example, the documentation for `curve_fit()` at  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html says:

> Returns:   popt : array 
>     Optimal values for the parameters so that the sum of the squared residuals of f(xdata, *popt) - ydata is minimized
>
> pcov : 2d array 
>     The estimated covariance of popt. The diagonals provide the variance of the parameter estimate. To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters use perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)).
>       How the sigma parameter affects the estimated covariance depends on absolute_sigma argument, as described above.

which is to say: use `p_sigma = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`

Allow me to suggest that for curve-fitting to Gaussian and Lorentzian models, you might find lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) helpful.  It provides built-in version for these and other Models.  Among other features, it can print a nicely formatted report for such a fit that includes uncertainties.

For an example, see https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-1-fit-peaked-data-to-gaussian-lorentzian-and-voigt-profiles